# Does the foreign key in sqlite store the whole value, or just the pointer to the actual value in other table?

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have a table with thousands of records, each of them have a field "Region", that can only have one of the 6 values - "North America", "South America", "Asia", etc. Will the size of the DB decrease if I create a separate table "Regions" and point original DB's region field to the new table as a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
My original table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(Region TEXT, Country TEXT, City TEXT, etc);
```

My first attempt to decrease size(that didn't work):

```
CREATE TABLE Regions(Region TEXT);
CREATE TABLE MyTable(Region TEXT, Country TEXT, City TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (Region) references Regions(Region));
```

New schema that actually worked:

```
CREATE TABLE Regions(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Region TEXT);
CREATE TABLE MyTable(RegionId INTEGER, Country TEXT, City TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (RegionId) REFERENCES Regions(ID));
```

Storing the integer value for Region decreased the size of the database a lot.

Comment: Performance gets worse, as expected, here are some results:  
original database:  
`sqlite> select count(*) from table where region="Asia";  
775473  
CPU Time: user 0.334413 sys 0.185405`  

modified database:
`sqlite> select count(*) from table2,regions where region="Asia" and regions.id=table2.regionid;`
775473
CPU Time: user 0.393923 sys 0.174680
  
Now I’m trying to figure out if the smaller database size is worth lower performance.

Comment: Worse for count(*) isn't in itself a bad thing. Test queries your app actually uses.

Answer (score 2):

Your region strings will be stored with one byte per character, while small numbers can be stored in a single byte.
So your database size will indeed decrease.

(The theoretical number of saved bytes could be determined with `SELECT SUM(LENGTH(Region) - 1) FROM MyTable`, but the dividing of pages into records, and the additional page needed to store the regions table, will reduce that.)

Comment: I created a separate table where I store foreign keys, changed the original table to reference to the new table, but the size of the DB didn't change. It should have decreased by a lot, because there are 1 million rows in the table, but it didn't. Did I forget to do something?